# How can I change the order of the data record with regular expression and put it together in one single dataframe?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

What I want to know is how I can use the above data frame with regular expression to put the data rows in the right order.
As you can see by for example   index 2 and 4, the Quantity and Piece are in the wrong order.
Does anyone have any idee how I can fix this?

```py
data = [['Total 8\r\r\nQuantity 2\r\r\nPiece 4'], ['Total 8\r\r\nQuantity 2\r\r\nPiece 4'],['Total 8\r\r\nPiece 2\r\r\nQuantity 4'], ['Total 8\r\r\nQuantity 2\r\r\nPiece 4'], ['Total 8\r\r\nPiece 2\r\r\nQuantity 4'],['Total 8\r\r\nQuantity 2\r\r\nPiece 4'], ['Total 8\r\r\nQuantity 2\r\r\nPiece 4'],['Total 8\r\r\nPiece 2\r\r\nQuantity 4'], ['Total 8\r\r\nQuantity 2\r\r\nPiece 4'], ['Total 8\r\r\nPiece 2\r\r\nQuantity 4']] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Information']) 
df 

+-------+--------------------------------------+
| index |             Information              |
+-------+--------------------------------------+
|     0 | Total 8\r\r\nQuantity 2\r\r\nPiece 4 |
|     1 | Total 8\r\r\nQuantity 2\r\r\nPiece 4 |
|     2 | Total 8\r\r\nPiece 2\r\r\nQuantity 4 |
|     3 | Total 8\r\r\nQuantity 2\r\r\nPiece 4 |
|     4 | Total 8\r\r\nPiece 2\r\r\nQuantity 4 |
|     5 | Total 8\r\r\nQuantity 2\r\r\nPiece 4 |
|     6 | Total 8\r\r\nQuantity 2\r\r\nPiece 4 |
|     7 | Total 8\r\r\nPiece 2\r\r\nQuantity 4 |
|     8 | Total 8\r\r\nQuantity 2\r\r\nPiece 4 |
|     9 | Total 8\r\r\nPiece 2\r\r\nQuantity 4 |
+-------+--------------------------------------+


dt = pd.DataFrame(df)
data = []
for item in dt['Information']:
    regex = re.findall(r"(\d+)\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)",item)
    quantity = re.findall(r"\bTotal\s?\d\D+(\bQuantity)",item)
    piece = re.findall(r"\bTotal\s?\d\D+(\bPiece)",item)
    regex = (map(list,regex))
    data.append(list(map(int,list(regex)[0])))
dftotal = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Total','Quantity','Piece'])
print(dftotal)
```

With this code I got a column like below

```
+-------+----------+-------+
| Total | Quantity | Piece |
+-------+----------+-------+
|     8 |        2 |     4 |
|     8 |        2 |     4 |
|     8 |        2 |     4 |
|     8 |        2 |     4 |
|     8 |        2 |     4 |
|     8 |        2 |     4 |
|     8 |        2 |     4 |
|     8 |        2 |     4 |
|     8 |        2 |     4 |
+-------+----------+-------+
```

How can I get a dataframe like below by switching those wrong order from de 'data array' and put the right variables in a single dataframe?

```
+-------+----------+-------+   
| Total | Quantity | Piece |
+-------+----------+-------+
|     8 |        2 |     4 |
|     8 |        4 |     2 |
|     8 |        2 |     4 |
|     8 |        4 |     2 |
|     8 |        2 |     4 |
|     8 |        2 |     4 |
|     8 |        4 |     2 |
|     8 |        2 |     4 |
|     8 |        4 |     2 |
+-------+----------+-------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one approach using `str.extract`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['Total 8\r\r\nQuantity 2\r\r\nPiece 4'], ['Total 8\r\r\nQuantity 2\r\r\nPiece 4'],['Total 8\r\r\nPiece 2\r\r\nQuantity 4'], ['Total 8\r\r\nQuantity 2\r\r\nPiece 4'], ['Total 8\r\r\nPiece 2\r\r\nQuantity 4'],['Total 8\r\r\nQuantity 2\r\r\nPiece 4'], ['Total 8\r\r\nQuantity 2\r\r\nPiece 4'],['Total 8\r\r\nPiece 2\r\r\nQuantity 4'], ['Total 8\r\r\nQuantity 2\r\r\nPiece 4'], ['Total 8\r\r\nPiece 2\r\r\nQuantity 4']] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Information'])

df["Total"] = df["Information"].str.extract(r"Total (\d+)")
df["Quantity"] = df["Information"].str.extract(r"Quantity (\d+)")
df["Piece"] = df["Information"].str.extract(r"Piece (\d+)")
df.drop("Information", inplace=True, axis=1)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  Total Quantity Piece
0     8        2     4
1     8        2     4
2     8        4     2
3     8        2     4
4     8        4     2
5     8        2     4
6     8        2     4
7     8        4     2
8     8        2     4
9     8        4     2
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact the original data is close to a csv file where the separator would be a space. Once the data is loaded that way, pivoting it would be enough to get what you want.

So I would do:

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('\r\r\n'.join((line[0] for line in data))),
                 sep=' ', header=None)

df['n'] = (df.index / 3).astype(np.int32)

result = df.pivot('n', 0, 1)
```

result is the following dataframe:

```
0  Piece  Quantity  Total
n                        
0      4         2      8
1      4         2      8
2      2         4      8
3      4         2      8
4      2         4      8
5      4         2      8
6      4         2      8
7      2         4      8
8      4         2      8
9      2         4      8
```